# How to label by grouping categories in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am working on bacterial symbiotic with marine organism. clustermap/heatmap using R.  I would like to group the genes into categories as given in  and label the xticks accordingly. Although I know how to generate the heatmap using R, I am unsure about how to label  as categories.
suppose this is my example data set

```
    df <- data.frame(
  Category = c("Ank", "Ank", "Ank", "Toxin", "Toxin", "Toxin", "TPR", "TPR"),
  Gene = c(
    "Tubulin (PF00091.26)",
    "PD40 (PF07676.13)",
    "HEAT_2 (PF13646.7)",
    "DUF4097 (PF13349.7)",
    "fn3_5 (PF06280.13)",
    "fn3 (PF00041.22)",
    "Cad (PF03596.14)",
    "Big_2 (PF02368.19)"
  ),
  Bacillus_sp1 = c(1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Bacillus_sp2 = c(1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1),
  Bacillus_sp3 = c(1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Bacillus_sp4 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0)
)

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

Image which I got from one paper.

[image]

I tried a lot but I couldn't, kindly help

Comment: Please share your code and (a subset of) your data. Where does the provided reference image come from? Is that what you got so far or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Till, I have done some aditional changes, kindly look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the person that created the heatmap for the paper did
some manual editing of the heatmap to add the categories.
We can achieve similar results either by using `ggplot2::facet_wrap()`
or by using `ggh4x::guide_axis_nested()`.

#### `facet_wrap()`

```r
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  pivot_longer(-c(Category, Gene)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Gene, name, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value,
                color = ifelse(value < 1, "light", "dark"))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(light = "white", dark = "black"),
                     guide = "none") +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  facet_wrap( ~ Category, scales = "free_x") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

#### `ggh4x::guide_axis_nested()`

```r
library(ggh4x)

df |>
  pivot_longer(-c(Category, Gene)) |>
  mutate(Gene = paste(Gene, Category, sep = "&&")) |>
  ggplot(aes(Gene, name, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value,
                color = ifelse(value < 1, "light", "dark"))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(light = "white", dark = "black"),
                     guide = "none") +
  guides(x = ggh4x::guide_axis_nested(delim = "&&")) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]